# create custom cells

Tags: datagridview

I have tables `customer`, `order`, `item`. The procedure is that when I receive order I fulfill it through order `Form` with items and job to do on items on it. I have row for every item with status on my order. It can be multiple items on one order, with some job to do on every item.

Can I show in `datagridview` like:

[image]

But keep in mind that `Flex print`, `Lamination`, `Digital print`, `Offset` are all in table order as `job to do` on items ordered.

On single order I can have multiple items that need to be laminated, but I would like to show *(as in image above)* only status as checked when all of my items on order are laminated. Is this even doable?

Comment: There are so many questions to ask here, What database system are you looking to use? The answer to your question would be, yes it is possible. But you are going to have learn about relational databases to understand how you can achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

You should set data type of those columns to boolean.